# Why is my computer so loud?

Tags: noise

My Linux box is making a lot of noise, and I don't know if it's normal. A friend gave me his old computer and I only recently got around to turning it on again. I don't remember it being this loud when he showed it to me. Here's a video with sound: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TFb6.jpg

Any ideas? I don't know much about building computers. It *sounds* like a fan or something cyclical.

Comment: See if it the fan making noise (fairly common). Open the case and see if you can pinpoint the fan.

Comment: @John, the fan is in the video. I honestly can't tell where the noise is coming from.

Comment: If you can't tell with stereo ears, we can't tell from a mono recording. Stick your finger in each fan to stop it for a couple of seconds. That will quickly tell you. the rear fan is running very very slowly & is also wearing about a decade of dust bunny. First job would be to blow the entire machine out to at least give it half a chance to breathe.

Comment: @Tetsujin, apologies for my question, then. I assumed hearing + knowledge was better than simply hearing. I'll try cleaning things.

Comment: Those fans are REALLY DIRTY.  Until you clean them, we can't know if the bearings inside are still good or not.  Clean or replace your fans.. one at a time using the advice from @Tetsujin.  Also.. if you use a lot of air to clean it out, hold the fans still while blowing it out so they don't spin at 2,000,000,000 RPMS (that will shorten whatever life they have left)

Comment: as an addendum to @SeñorCMasMas 's comment -  if you get a really good blower [about $£€ 50 for one that will last you a lifetime or more; as opposed to a fiver or so for a can of compressed air from a computer shop that will last almost 5 minutes] then do it at least in front of a wide-open window, if not actually outdoors. As I recently discovered, it's far easier to let the wind clean the yard than it is to hoover & dust down the carpet, curtains, table, picture frames, sofas, cat, mother-in-law… ;))

Comment: Not scientific, but that CPU fan seems a possible suspect to me. In general, perhaps check for any looseness in the fans' mountings (i.e. can you wiggle them or gently tighten the screws). Also, stray wires hitting fan blades could be an issue. You can likely replace the fans as well, obviously or (on the cheap) maybe consider removing them temporarily, hitting any rotating components in them with some dry graphite lubricant from the hardware store.

Comment: In many cases, a good vacuum cleaner will also do the job, with no leftovers.

Comment: @harrymc - agreed, that's what I did for years before I bought the blower. The blower, however, is much faster & more efficient than a vac (if a whole lot messier;). Wish I'd bought one years ago.

Comment: @Tetsujin, okay, it's definitely the fan. I cleaned it with compressed air, and then put my finger on it while the computer was running. The noise stops when the fan stops. You can see in the video that the fan jerks periodically, which suggests its bearings are bad.

Comment: I'd just grab a new fan from eBay then. They're pretty cheap & identification on a case fan is little more complicated than "case fan *xyz* mm wide & has *nn* pins" [size & socket type.]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to scan for viruses using an antivirus software, if your antivirus software dosent detect anything then check how much dust is present in your fan, clean the dust, there are many methods available or hand it over to a professional for further examination.